# Why is numpy.array() creating an array without the correct shape?

Tags: python-3.x, list, numpy, dimensions, numpy-ndarray

I want to numpy.concatenate two numpy.arrays I am creating from a two different lists. I should note that the data in the lists are different types.

I have created two lists. Both I have created numpy arrays. Then I attempt to concatenate. I get an error that says: "all the input arrays must have the same number of dimensions".

```py
l1 = [1, ..., n]
l2 = [1, ..., n]

print(len(l1)) # returns n
print(len(l2)) # returns n

a1 = np.array(l1)
a2 = np.array(l2)

print(np.shape(a1)) # returns (1, n)
print(np.shape(a1.T) # returns (n, 1)
print(np.shape(a2)) # returns (n,)

try:
    data = np.concatenate((a1.T, a2), axis=1) # epic fail; computer laughs at me
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

I should note the data of one of the lists consist of map objects. Not sure if that is an issue. But the variable l1 itself is a list.

Comment: I should note the original code was written in Python 2 which used a `l2.append(map(float, data_point))`. After reviewing the change of the map() behavior change from Python 2 and 3, https://portingguide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/iterators.html, I changed my code as described in the link. There is another error that comes up in a higher level function that may be related. (Note: the rank for the arrays were the same when I tested it)

Comment: Check the `dtype` as well as `shape`.  If both lists contain just numbers, then the shape should be `(n,)`.  I don't know how you get `(1,n)` - that implies an extra layer of `[]`.  `map` does require adjustment between Py2 and 3.  And `concatenate` requires a consistent number of dimensions.

Comment: It seems to have fixed it when I replaced the list of map object. Before it was: `l2.append(map(float, data))`. I switched it to: `l2.append([float(x) for x in data])`. It fixed errors I was getting with the error above and "too many indices in array". I should also add, the python script was not created by me, but included output graphs that look accurate based on previous output results. According to that link I attached, it says map() was changed from 2.x to 3.x. Not sure why, but the change worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think part of the problem might be that the two arrays have different numpy rank, namely `len(a1.shape)==2` whereas `len(a2.shape)==1`. You can add a dummy axis with `np.newaxis` or just `None`.  For example, the following seems to work

```py
import numpy as np
l1 = [[1,2,3,4]]
l2 = ['a','b','c','d']
a1 = np.array(l1)
a2 = np.array(l2)
print(a1.T.shape)
print(a2[:,None].shape)
data = np.hstack((a1.T, a2[:,None]))
print(data)
```

which produces the output

```
$ python3 demo.py                                                               
(4, 1)
(4, 1)
[['1' 'a']
 ['2' 'b']
 ['3' 'c']
 ['4' 'd']]
```

Of course, numpy arrays require homogeneous data types (which can be `object`) and `concatenate` and friends may cast in ways might not like.